# AutoGenerated Id as Primary key + Unique constraint Vs Multiple columns primary key. Easier relationships of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datatable

I have some SQL tables defined as

```
[ITEMS]
- Id (PK)
- Name

[SUPPLIERS]
- Id(PK)
- Name

[ITEM_SUPPLIERS]
- Id_Item(PK)
- Id_supplier(PK)
- Effective_date(PK)
- Currency(PK)
- UnitCount
- Cost

[ITEM_SUPPLIER_EXTENDED]
- Id_Item(PK)
- Id_supplier(PK)
- Effective_date(PK)
- Currency(PK)
- IdExtendedInfo (PK)

[EXTENDED_INFORMATION]
- IdExtendedInfo (PK)
- InfoData
```

I want to know why/ why not will be a good idea to declare an `Id_Item_Supplier` in `ITEM_SUPPLIERS` and relate with other tables by this ID, instead of all `ITEM_SUPPLIERS` PKs. Also i will add a `Unique` constraint to force the uniqueness of the data.

Basically I want to avoid to copy all the PKs columns from `ITEM_SUPPLIER` to other Tables that are related to it.

Result:

```
  [ITEM_SUPPLIERS]
  - Id_Item_Supplier(PK)
  - Id_Item(FK)
  - Id_supplier(FK)
  - Effective_date(FK)
  - Currency(FK)
  - Cost
  - Comments
   (UNIQUE)[Id_Item,Id_supplier,Effective_date,Currency]


  [ITEM_SUPPLIER_EXTENDED]
  - Id_Item_Supplier(PK)
  - IdExtendedInfo (PK)
```

Comment: Those aren't create scripts, but does your table `ITEM_SUPPLIER_EXTENDED` have a Primary key made up of every column in the table, and `ITEM_SUPPLIERS` has one made up of 4 of them? Ideally, you should be using a single column, or at most 2 (if the table is a composite key table, for many to many relationship). Doing it the way you have makes it very hard to build relationships between the data, and makes a `JOIN` very crowded if you're having to declare 4/5 expressions.

Comment: Yes, ITEM_SUPPLIER_EXTENDED has a PK. ITEM_SUPPLIERS  has 4 fields that compose the PK  but I think that they could be converted to a Unique Key  .What  Do you think ?

Comment: This is a long time open issue. search the web for surrogate key vs natural key and you will see that while everyone have an opinion about it, there is no conclusive consensual best practice for it.  As such, this question is off-topic since it's primarily opinion based. My personal opinion - nothing wrong with a surrogate key, as long as the natural key is also enforced via unique constraints (or indexes) and non-nullable columns.

Comment: Ok, i wanted to know just if there are advantages or disadvantages, that's not should be an opinion. But thank you by your help sir

Comment: [Here is a good place to start.](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=surrogate+key+vs+natural+key+pros+and+cons&rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&oq=surrogate+key+vs+natural+key+pros+and+cons&aqs=chrome..69i57.12399j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> I want to know why/ why not will be a good idea to declare an Id_Item_Supplier in ITEM_SUPPLIERS and relate with other tables by this ID, instead of all ITEM_SUPPLIERS PKs.

It *is* a good idea to have a separate, single column which is the primary key for each table.  In fact, I create such columns pretty much be default, using the name of the table (in singular) followed by `id` or `_id`.

This column would generally be an `identity` column or some sort of guid column (using `newsequentialid()`).  Why is a single column useful?  Here are some reasons:

- Referencing tables can use a single column, rather than multiple columns.
- `JOIN`s are safer -- no danger of leaving out a key.
- A single fixed-length column is (slightly) more efficient for indexes than variable-width columns (only applies if any of the other columns are variable length).
- An identity column also records the order of inserts, which can be handy.

Comment: Ok, there is any reason against doing that?

Comment: Another pro point for surrogate keys is storage size - you don't have to carry around all the natural key columns through the entire length of related tables - and in large databases, that can make a lot of difference.

Comment: @Badulake . . . In some cases, the surrogate key can occupy a few extra bytes, if another column would work.  That is usually of minimal importance.